# update subscription without updating the firestore real time

Tags: angular

I subscribe to an angular firestore collection from my ionic app using valueChanges function of AngularFirestoreCollection. but I don't need to get my data updated in real time. I only need the data which was present at the time of subscription. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [take(1)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) or [first()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/first) rxjs operator.